# How to check if a word is included between quotation marks?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how I could detect a specific word, for example `python` if it is included within quotation marks ('' or "") or is not. 
I have the following sentences:

```
    Name              Sentences

    John                In the book it is written: "Python is a programming language code"
    Mary                "Go away from me, Python!!!"
   Chris                 I love Python.
```

I would like to have only rows with Python between quotation marks:

```
Name              Sentences

    John                In the book it is written: "Python is a programming language code"
    Mary                "Go away from me, Python!!!"
   Chris                 I love Python.
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I have thought that probably regex could be helpful for this task. My main issue is to add the condition 'between quotation marks'.

Comment: Provided the string contains at most one pair of double-quotes you could use the regex `r'\"[^\"\r\n]*\b(Python)\b.*\"'`. [Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/9d71jL/2/) and match `"Python"` in capture group 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `str.extract` , the do `contains`

```
df['Sentences'].str.extract('"([^"]*)"').iloc[:,0].str.contains('Python',case=False)
```

Comment: This might be simpler `df['Sentences'].str.contains('"(.)*Python(.)*"',case=False)`

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://regex101.com/r/SjWdUg/1]
This can be delt with a Regex query from here: https://regex101.com/r/SjWdUg/1

`.*\".*\b(?:Python|python)\b.*\".*`

There is also a built in regex code generator there which you can use.

```py
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r".*\".*\b(?:Python|python)\b.*\".*"

test_str = ("    Name              Sentences\n\n"
    "    John                In the book it is written: \"Python is a programming language code\"\n"
    "    Mary                \"Go away from me, Python!!!\"\n"
    "   Chris                 I love Python. ")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```